# Cplusplus std::set of bidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, stdset

I'm new to C++ and I need to use `Set` from the `STL` but I'm struggling with the concept.

I have an array like this `int my_data[3]`

I want to create (don't know if this is possible) a `set` with space for 3 ints and that the `key` for the `set` would be the `int` that is stored on the first column.

I also want to make a custom sort.

This is what I've tried but with no success.

```
struct sort_set {
    bool operator() (const int& a, const int& b) const {
        int* arr1 = (int*) a;
        int* arr2 = (int*) b;
        int diff = arr2[1] - arr1[1];
        if (diff) {
            return true;
        } else if (diff == 0) {
            int diff2 = arr2[2] - arr1[2];
            if (diff2) {
                return false;
            }

        }
        return arr1[0] < arr2[0];
    }
};

set<int[3],sort_set> data;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your `sort_set` is not a strict weak ordering.  For example, with `a = {0,1,0}` and `b = {0,2,0}`, you have both `sort_set()(a,b)` and `sort_set()(b,a)` are true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have arrays as elements of containers. They're not assignable nor copyable.

Use `std::array<int, 3>` if you have C++11 avaliable, or define a custom class otherwise.

Comment: Thanks.  And if I create a class with 3 int,  how can I define witch one is the set key?

Comment: You write a custom comparator (as you did above) and compare the one you want.

Comment: You access the elements through iterators. But to get an iterator, you often use a search, which uses the comparator too.